# How to stop on first error - reactor Flux filterWhen()

Tags: java, project-reactor

I am using Flux's filterWhen in a similar situation like below. If an error occurs in the method "isLessThan10", it does not stop, but continues with other items in the Flux to finally throw "MultipleExceptions".

Currently I m using .onErrorMap() to unwrap the original error from MulipleException but I want to STOP on first error instead.

Any suggestions?

Code

```
    @Test
    public void test() {
        Mono<List<Integer>> mono = Flux.just(20, 0, 0, 15)
                .filterWhen(this::isLessThan10)
                .collectList();

        System.out.println(mono.block());
    }

    private Mono<Boolean> isLessThan10(final int value) {
        return Mono.just(100/value < 10);
    }
```

Result:

```
reactor.core.Exceptions$CompositeException: Multiple exceptions

    at reactor.core.Exceptions.multiple(Exceptions.java:120)
    at reactor.core.Exceptions.addThrowable(Exceptions.java:92)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterWhen$FluxFilterWhenSubscriber.drain(FluxFilterWhen.java:255)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterWhen$FluxFilterWhenSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterWhen.java:140)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxArray$ArraySubscription.slowPath(FluxArray.java:127)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxArray$ArraySubscription.request(FluxArray.java:100)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterWhen$FluxFilterWhenSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilterWhen.java:200)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxArray.subscribe(FluxArray.java:53)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxArray.subscribe(FluxArray.java:59)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4099)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1702)
    at StopOnErrorTest.test(StopOnErrorTest.java:15)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:221)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
    Suppressed: java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
        at StopOnErrorTest.isLessThan10(StopOnErrorTest.java:19)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterWhen$FluxFilterWhenSubscriber.drain(FluxFilterWhen.java:252)
        ... 31 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
        at StopOnErrorTest.isLessThan10(StopOnErrorTest.java:19)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterWhen$FluxFilterWhenSubscriber.drain(FluxFilterWhen.java:252)
        ... 31 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
        at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:99)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1703)
        ... 23 more
```

**Work Around:**
To use filter() instead of filterWhen(), had to replace "filterWhen" with "flatMap -> filter -> map"

```
    @Test
    public void test_FlatMap_Filter() {
        Mono<List<Integer>> mono = Flux.just(20, 0, 0, 15)
                .flatMap(this::isLessThan10)
                .filter(Pair::getRight)
                .map(Pair::getLeft)
                .collectList();

        System.out.println(mono.block());
    }

    private Mono<Pair<Integer, Boolean>> isLessThan10(final int value) {
        return Mono.just(Pair.of(value, 100/value < 10));
    }
```

This gives me the expected behavior. But it was convenient to use filterWhen() in my case.

Comment: Why do you use `filterWhen()` instead of `filter()`?

Comment: Hi, please check **Work Around** section in the question. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Why is `filterWhen()` more convenient for you than using `filter()`? The method `filterWhen()` is, by definition, checking the values asynchronously. So it can happen (as in your case), that some checks can result in exceptions asynchronously, which will be collected at the end. Why do you need `filterWhen()` when `filter()` works just fine and intentionally?

Comment: This is an intended behavior of `filterWhen` that all errors are suppressed and combined in a single `CompositeException`. `filterWhen` was inspired by `filterAsync()` in RxJava and I suppose that's the reason for the similar behavior.